# Excel: Change ####### in a cell to n/a

Tags: excel, formula

Excel question how to change ####### (shows up this way when data exceeds what the cell can display) in a cell to n/a without using VBA? I can do it manually by expanding the width of a column but I want to keep the spreadsheet small and don't need 9999999% its meaningless. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Something like `=IF(x < 1000, x, "n/a")` should do it (where `1000` is whatever cutoff you choose).

Comment: If you're not using VBA, it's probably not programming :-)

Answer (score 1):

Select one or more cells you want to change; perhaps start with the cells that are showing 'meaningless' values like 9999999%. Note the 'active cell'. This is typically the cell in the top-left corner of a selected group of cells. For the sake of demonstration, that cell will be D2.

Use Home ► Styles ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. When the New Formatting Rule dialog opens, choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* then supply the following in the *Format values where this formula is true:* textbox.

```
=ABS(D2)>10
```

A raw value of 10 is 1000%. Anything that is greater than 1000% or less than -1000% will receive the conditional formatting. Note that D2 is involved in the formula.

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and when the Format Cells dialog opens, go to the Number tab and choose *Custom* from the list down the left. Supply the following in the *Type:* textbox,

```
"n/a"
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to accept the new formatting then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

Repeat for other cells that may have values showing other scope(s) that you consider 'meaningless'.